# Start compiz with additional options, but from which script?

Tags: 12.04, compiz, session

I'm experiencing general sluggishness on my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop and read at http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/NVIDIA_Quadro_NVS_140M (which is my graphics card) that the following env variable and options to `compiz` may fix the issue:

```
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
compiz ccp --indirect-rendering --loose-binding --sm-disable --replace
```

What is the best file from which to issue the above commands? I am having difficulty finding the script that executes `compiz` at login.

According to the `ps` command, compiz is started by `gnome-session --session=ubuntu` and a look in /usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session shows references to compiz but I am not sure that this is the correct place to pass options to compiz and set the above env variable.